# Aligning items with flexbox in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to align Views in React Native, and I want that every View is 50% of the screen. Something like :

[image]

My state is :

```
this.state = {
    companies: [
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/ald.png")},
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/arval.png")},
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/businesslease.png")},
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/dieterenusedcars.png")},
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/psa.png")},
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/remarketing_center.png")},
         {logo_url: require("../../../img/company_logos/vdfin.png")}
   ]
}
```

And then in the render method :

```
render(){
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    {this.state.companies.map(company => {
                        return (
                            <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5, height: 150}}>
                                <Image source={company.logo_url} style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5, height: 100}}/>
                            </View>
                        );
                    })}
                </View>
    )
}
```

But I see only first two logos.

All items are probably shown in one row instead of going to second row if there is no more place on the screen.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case somebody else has the same problem.

I solved it by adding `flexWrap: "wrap"` to the parent `View`

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
```